# How to catch primefaces schedule next / previous event?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am using primefaces schedule i want to call javascript function when user press previous / next button of schedule.

Comment: If these events are not defined, the only option iscto override the PrimeFaces source

Comment: See my comment above… learn about event handlers etc..